# Plot eigenvalues of a matrix with two variables

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, eigenvalues

I am trying to plot eigenvalues E(kx,ky) of the matrix [mat] depends on two variables kx and ky and of course n its dimension  , and the matrix elements a, b and c depend on cos(kx) ; cos (ky) and cos(kz) ;the interval of k-variables (kx,ky) is from (0,0)  to (Pi,Pi),

```
f = 2.87*10^-10
a=0.2*(2.4-(Cos[f*ky]+Cos[f*kx]))+4;
b=4*Cos[f*ky]*Cos[f*kx]*Cos[f*kz];
c=4;
kz=0;
 

n = 2;

(mat =ReplacePart[DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[a + b , n]] + DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-c, n - 1], 1] + DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-c, n - 1], -1],{{1, 1} -> a, {n, n} -> a }])
```

Comment: Mathematica is case-sensitive, `cos[x]` (undefined) is not the same as `Cos[x]` (Cosine trigonometrical function, suitable for both symbolic and numerical manipulation).

Comment: Do **NOT** use single-letter uppercase symbols. Many of those are used internally and you can run into conflicts. In your case, `C` is a protected symbol and the assignment does not work. Use `a, b, c` instead.

Comment: Technically, posts belong to the site/community. A lot deference is given to the wishes of the original author, but the author should not alter a question so much as your last edits.

Comment: BTW, I'm not one of the downvoters. I assumed you were new and didn't understand how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

Using your code above, define a function that calculates the eigenvalues for numerical values of kx and ky:

```
ev[x_, y_] := Eigenvalues[mat /. {kx -> x, ky -> y}];
```

Calculate all the values you want, here I have done x's between 1 and 4 (with stepsize 1) and between 1 and 5 for y.

```
vals = Table[ev[xa, ya], {xa, 1, 4, 1}, {ya, 1, 5, 1}];
```

Then plot:

```
ListPlot3D[vals]
```

[image]

The above plots all 4 eigenvalues in different colors. You may want to plot (say, just the first ones), so you could do:

```
ListPlot3D[vals[[All, 1]]]
```

Comment: There are 4 eigenvalues, your plot only shows 2. Also, you are plotting only for kya=kyb, whereas you asked for a plot with both variables (which is why I potted using ListPLot3D). To accomplish your goal, calculate vals with ev[xa,xa] with xa going from 0 to Pi. Then use ListPlot on Transpose[vals].